# Override Theme table function used in contributed module?

Tags: 7, theming, ubercart

There is function used in [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) module :

```
function theme_uc_recurring_user_table($variables) {
    ........
}
```

I want to override result of this function and did by below method in `template.php` file of my theme:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_table(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
    if (current_path() == "user/me/recurring-fees") {
      if(!$variables['header'][7]) {
        $variables['header'][7] = "Donation";
      }
      if(!$variables['rows'][0]['data'][7]) {
        $variables['rows'][0]['data'][7] = l('Update Donation', '/donation');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I just added table column header and data below that. But I did this by current path but I think there must be some right approach.

I am trying to find but not able to figure out how exactly we can achieve this.

Please suggest !! Thanks

Comment: Try `MYTHEME_preprocess_uc_recurring_user_table()` ?

Comment: I though this is possible with only theme function and not table function. I will try this now. Thanks!

Comment: In this way it does not give out put of rows and data. I think its not working this way. Output come like  `Array ( [uid] => 1116 [context] => Array ( ) [theme_hook_original] => uc_recurring_user_table [theme_hook_suggestions] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: How about overriding `theme_uc_recurring_user_table()` with [`hook_theme_registry_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7.x)? Do you feel comfortable with altering theme registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`theme_uc_recurring_user_table()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/uc_recurring/tree/uc_recurring.module#n943) **is** a theme hook (not a table function), and its preprocess function is `hook_preprocess_uc_recurring_user_table()`.
From the preprocess function you can just change the content of `$variables` which, in the case of `theme_theme_uc_recurring_user_table()` just contains `$variables['uid']`.

What you need to do is overriding the theme hook implemented from the module, which is quite easy, since you are doing it from a theme.

```
function MYTHEME_uc_recurring_user_table($variables) {
  $uid = $variables['uid'];
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'uc_recurring') . '/uc_recurring.css');

  // Set up a header array for the table.
  $header = array(t('Order'), t('Amount'), t('Interval'), t('Next charge'), t('Status'), t('Remaining'), t('Options'));

  if ($GLOBALS['user']->uid) {
    $header[] = t('Donations');
  }

  $recurring_states = uc_recurring_fee_status_label();

  // Build an array of rows representing the user's fees.
  $rows = array();

  foreach (uc_recurring_get_user_fees($uid) as $fee) {
    // Get the user operations links for the current fee.
    $ops = uc_recurring_get_fee_ops('user', $fee);

    // Add the row to the table for display.
    $rows[] = array(
      'data' => array(
        l($fee->order_id, 'user/' . $uid . '/order/' . $fee->order_id),
        theme('uc_price', $fee->fee_amount),
        array(
          'data' => check_plain($fee->regular_interval),
          'nowrap' => 'nowrap',
        ),
        format_date($fee->next_charge, 'short'),
        '<span class="recurring-status-' . intval($fee->status) . '">' . $recurring_states[$fee->status] . '</span>',
        $fee->remaining_intervals < 0 ? t('Until cancelled') : $fee->remaining_intervals,
        array(
          'data' => implode(' | ', $ops),
          'nowrap' => 'nowrap',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  if (empty($rows)) {
    $rows[] = array(array(
        'data' => t('Your account has no recurring fees.'),
        'colspan' => 7,
      ));
  }
  elseif ($GLOBALS['user']->uid) {
    $rows[0]['data'][] = l('Update Donation', '/donation');
  }

  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}
```

Comment: `quite easy` becomes `quite east` lol

Comment: Because _t_ is on the western side of _y_.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno and jimmy Ko for helping and explaining!!